# Save zip of pdf in folder with jszip

Tags: javascript, pdf, zip, jszip

i don't get how to properly use jsZip..
i'm trying to get a file from a folder in localhost then zip it and at last save the zipped file in the same folder...

but really i don't have good comprension on how to use it

here what i have done :

```
        JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent("http://localhost:8100/pdf/test.pdf", function (err, data) {
      if(err) {
          alert('err');
          throw err;
      }
      else{
        zip.file("test.pdf",data,{binary:true})
        .then(function (blob) {
            saveAs(blob, "pdf.zip");
        });
      }  
    });
```

can anibody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following bit of code is what ended up working for me.

NB, this is for jszip utils version 3. It needs filesaver.js to make the saveAs call work (https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js).

Here's my code:

```
function create_zip(){
    // get checked file urls
    var urls = Array();
    $("input:checked").each(function () {
        urls.push($(this).siblings('a').attr('href'));
    })
console.log(urls);

    var zip = new JSZip();
    var count = 0;
    var zipFilename = "archive.zip";

    urls.forEach(function(url){
      var filename = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
console.log(filename);
      // loading a file and add it in a zip file
      JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
         if(err) {
            throw err; // or handle the error
         }
         zip.file(filename, data, {binary:true});
         count++;

        if (count == urls.length) {
           zip.generateAsync({type:'blob'}).then(function(content) {
              saveAs(content, zipFilename);
           });
        }
      });
    });
};
```

This is adapted from the info here: https://gist.github.com/noelvo/4502eea719f83270c8e9

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

```
 var zip = new JSZip();
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
      if(err) {
          alert('err');
          throw err;
      }
      else{
        zip.file("test.csv",data,{binary:true});
        zip.generateAsync({ type: "Blob" }).then(function (content) {
        fsaver.saveAs(content, "example.zip");
    });
      }  
    });
```

try this for angular. this one is for csv file. give url as the path of the csv file.

Comment: What is `fsaver`?

Comment: @DavidGiven It converts blob object into file.
its reference of NPM package.
package name: file-saver v.1.3.8